# Adding new line terminator to the end of every line

Tags: c, newline, memmove

What is the best way to add a '\r' to my new-line sequence? I am writing a string to a file and doing various parsing to it but according to my assignment spec a new line will be considered '\r\n'.

Right now I only have a new line at the end. I was thinking of a for loop and/or using memmove but not sure exactly how to make it work?

```
for (int x = 0;x < strlen(string);x++)
{
    if (string[x] == '\n')
    {
        ..............
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't simply append an additional character to the end of a string if you haven't made room for it.  Your code doesn't show how `string` is defined and initialized.

Comment: What are you doing now? How does it not work? Provide complete code.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Why not let the system handle that by including `\n` in the output string, after opening the output file in text mode. If the system typically uses `"\r\n"` then `"\n"` will be automatically expanded (or contracted on a read).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is something along the lines of:

1. Check that the last two characters in string aren't already "\r\n", if they are return string.
2. Check whether the last character in string has either '\r' or '\n', set a flag.
3. Allocate `strlen(string) + 2` bytes to hold the new string, if the flag is set, otherwise allocate `strlen(string) + 3` bytes.
4. Calculate `bytes to copy` as `strlen(string) - 1` if flag is set, otherwise `strlen(string)`.
5. Copy number of `bytes to copy`from `string` to the allocated storage.
6. Append "\r\n\0" to the end of the bytes copied above.
7. Return the string just created in allocated storage.

EDIT: Your mileage may vary if you can make assumptions about the state of `string`. If it resides in a large enough buffer to add characters to the end of it, no new allocation would be required. If your `char` type is not one byte, you would need to adjust accordingly.